# Effcient collision attack for the Davies-Meyer compression function

Tags: hash, block-cipher, pseudo-random-permutation

We have a block cipher $E:\{0,1\}^{128}\times\{0,1\}^{128}\rightarrow\{0,1\}^{128}$.

We know that the PRP advantage of E is **Adv**$_E^{PRP}=t/2^{128}$ where $t$ is the time needed by the algorithm to get the maximum advantage.

From $E$ we define $E'$ such that $E':\{0,1\}^{128}\times\{0,1\}^{128}\rightarrow\{0,1\}^{128}$ and $E'(k,\cdot)=E(k\bmod126,\cdot)$

Two questions:

1. What is the PRP advantage of $E'$
2. Propose an efficient collision attack for the Davies-Meyer compression function associated with $E'$

My guesses were for Q1 was $t/2^{128}$ also for $E'$ but it was really out of intuition so I am not sure.

The attack I propose for Q2 is the one with birthday bound but I was not able to elaborate any longer. Any help will be much appreciated specially because I lack some expertise in the basic concepts ...

Comment: Homework dump is off-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) unless it's shown what was done and where one is stuck. Throwing vague (and, it happens, invalid) "guesses" do not count. The $k\bmod126$ part of the question may have a typo. Suggestions: Get an understanding of what $E'$ is w.r.t. $E$, and what _"a collision attack for the Davies-Meyer compression function associated with $E′$"_ aims at producing. The second question is then easy. For the first question, write down the definition of $\mathsf{Adv}_E^{PRP}$, which is an indispensable step towards a solution.